# Don't show UIActivityIndicatorView when it loads fast enough (less than a second)

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityindicatorview

I was wondering if it's possible to not show the `UIActivityIndicatorView` when the loading of your data is fast enough (for example less than a second).

In my current app, my collection view gets reloaded at every new search, but sometimes the search is very fast, and the indicator view blinks and disappears instantly, giving an ugly overall feel to the app.

So basically my question is: can I "disable" the `UIActivityIndicatorView` when my loading is fast enough?

Comment: `view.hidden = true`?

Comment: but then the problem is, if the load time is 1,5 seconds, for the first second it won't show anything and then blink 0,5 seconds

Answer (score 1):

Using this class, I do not show activity indicator if callback is happening less than 1 sec.

```
final class DelayableActivityIndicatorView: UIActivityIndicatorView {
    static let kDefaultDelay: TimeInterval = 1
    private var inProgress = false

    func startAnimatingWithDelay(_ delay: TimeInterval = kDefaultDelay) {
        inProgress = true
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + delay) {
            if self.inProgress == true {
                self.startAnimating()
            }
            self.inProgress = false
        }
    }

    func stopAnimatingWithDelay() {
        inProgress = false
        stopAnimating()
    }
}
```

To use it in the view controller,

```
class MyViewController : UIViewController {
    override func loadView() {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .white

        self.view = view
    }

    var spinner: DelayableActivityIndicatorView = {
       let view = DelayableActivityIndicatorView(style: .gray)
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addSubview(spinner)
        spinner.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        spinner.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

        spinner.startAnimatingWithDelay()

        // replace this code with your network api
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) {
            self.spinner.stopAnimatingWithDelay()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

set a timer once you put a response to the server.if u get a reponse with in seconds you can hide the uiactivity indicator hidden by

```
activityindicator.hidden =false
```

Answer (score 0):

Sub class the UIActivityIndicatorView and override the setter for showing the view. Set a timer in here to only show after 2 seconds. If the activity indicator is dismissed before this then nothing will be shown.

Answer (score 0):

If it's impossible to know how many time your data employ to be taken, you can delay the showing of your `UIActivityIndicator` by using a timer or a delay func:

```
func delay(seconds seconds: Double, completion:()->()) {
        let popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64( Double(NSEC_PER_SEC) * seconds ))

        dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            completion()
        }
}
```

**Use**:

```
self.delay(seconds: 0.5, completion: {
            // show my activityindicator 
}
```

---

If you work with Alamofire framework to handle your network flow, you can also using the good **AlamofireNetworkActivityIndicator** [here](https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireNetworkActivityIndicator) with:

```
NetworkActivityIndicatorManager.sharedManager.startDelay = 1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You may simple delay start your indicator animate:

```
var inUpdate = false
let indicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView()

func startUpdate()
{
    // go to update request
    // do not forget to set inUpdate property to false in update completeon

    inUpdate = true
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))), dispatch_get_main_queue())
        {
            [weak self] in
            if self?.inUpdate == true
            {
                self!.indicatorView.startAnimating()
            }
        }
}
```